# Displaying a profile image in SharePoint (modern view)

Tags: list

I have a list of elements in which one of the types is Profile (Delve Profile). I edited the settings so that the list shows the Profile name and Picture, however this only happens in the classical view. When I go to the modern view I only get the profile name in that column. Is there anyway to make that work in modern view too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Column Formatting. A sample for working with a Person Field and showing a profile image can be found here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-roundimage-format

You could modify that sample to also show the user's name using this JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + @currentField.email",
            "title": "@currentField.title"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can find a guide for applying the format above to your column here: https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-list-formatting/gettingstarted/columnformats/

Comment: The link is broken as itthrows out a 404 page, unfortunately. Could you update the link, please?

Comment: No problem, thanks for letting me know!